# Ubuntu 14 running Samba CPU Utilization 100%

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, samba

I recently setup a virtual server running on Ubuntu 14.04 to take the place of a Mac server we were using for file sharing. The shared file directory probably has tens of thousands of files, and the 50ish users here are using OSX to connect. As soon as the first user connects the smbd CPU utilization jumps to 99%, if a second connects it spawns another process and splits the CPU to 49% each, if 10 users are connection the CPU utilization sits at about 12% each.

The host server is running dual Intel Xeon CPUs (2.3Mhz I think) with 8 cores each, I've tried allocating more RAM (16GB) and more vCPUs (4) to the guest, but I just end up in a spot where the CPU is still running hard, vmware reporting 10Ghz utilized and I'm sure its all smbd.

I've also tried netatalk and AFP instead of SMB, but the CPU gets hit just as hard. There are maybe 7 other VMs on this host, each allocated only 1 vCPU. I've found other threads reporting similar issues but no answers, is smb/afp really this CPU intensive? or is it the OSX clients? or maybe a config issue?

Samba Config

```
#Disable Printer Stuff
load printers = No
printing = bsd
printcap name = /dev/null
disable spoolss = Yes

#Disable nmbd
disable netbios = yes

#Logging
log level = 0


[Shared Docs]
path = "/usr/local/Shared/Files/Shared Docs"
valid users = adminuser
browsable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = no
```

Comment: Small update, I increased the amount of RAM allocated to 32GB instead of 16GB, and the server went from using all 16GB to only using ~6GB. I've tried 1,2, and 4 VCPU but the CPU utilization remains up near 100%.

Comment: tried many things, only change that has shown any promise is turning off the 'show icon preview' option in finder on the OSX clients for the network share. If that option is disabled when you open finder then no issues and the files pop up find without any significant CPU utilization. If the option is enabled CPU is hammered at 100% until smbd is restarted.

Comment: Disabling "show icon preview" also worked for me. It would be nice just to disable this for network shares.